# How to avoid NullPointerException on initial painting of Components?

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, awt

Currently I try to make a game of chess. This, the main class, calls a JPanel subclass, on which I draw the figures.

```
package schach;

public class schach extends JFrame {

  private SpielFeld spiel = new SpielFeld();

  public schach(String title) {

    Container cp = getContentPane();
    cp.add(spiel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new schach("Schach");
  }  
}
```

Then it continues with SpielFeld, the JPanel subclass, which is supposed to draw the figures and the board:

```
package schach;

public class SpielFeld extends JPanel {

  private Image brettimg =     new ImageIcon("schach\\sprites\\brett.png").getImage();
  private Image bauerWimg =    new ImageIcon("schach\\sprites\\bauerW.png").getImage();

  private ArrayList<Figur> figuren = new ArrayList<Figur>();

  private Bauer bauerW1 = new Bauer(6, 0);

  public SpielFeld() {
    figuren.add(bauerW1);
  }

  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    g.drawImage(brettimg, 0, 0, null);

    for (int i=0; i<figuren.size(); i++) {
      g.drawImage(bauerWimg, (int) figuren.get(i).getPoint().getX()*64, (int) figuren.get(i).getPoint().getY()*64, null);
    }    
  }
}
```

Now I do get a NullPointerException. I think this is because of the order in which "spiel" is created, the paintComponent is called (by default, uppon adding the JFrame to the ContentPane or something?) and the ArrayListed created and filled. I tried to comment out stuff to see how it work, but can't seem to figure it out. How does it work and how can I fix this? I tried to delete the hopefully unimportant stuff.

Figur.java

```
package schach;

public class Figur {

  Point posi;

  public Figur(int x, int y) {
    posi.setLocation(x, y);
  }

  public Point getPoint() {
    return posi;
  }
}
```

Bauer.java

```
package schach;

public class Bauer extends Figur {

  boolean zug = false;

  public Bauer(int x, int y) {
    super(x, y);
  }
}
```

@skirsch
This?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at schach.Figur.<init>(Figur.java:10)
    at schach.Bauer.<init>(Bauer.java:8)
    at schach.SpielFeld.<init>(SpielFeld.java:29)
    at schach.schach.<init>(schach.java:10)
    at schach.schach.main(schach.java:31)
```

Comment: please provide the stack trace of the exception

Comment: hmm ... haven't I seen this exact code recently? Same course ... ? Anyway, please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: 1) Test if the images are loaded. 2) Learn to use a debugger and step through the code. 3) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: 1) They are, I used another method before and it worked which the same code for loading the pictures. 3) That's what I tried to do :D

Answer (score 0):

In the class Figur the Point posi is not initialized and therefor null.
Replace

```
public Figur(int x, int y) {
    posi.setLocation(x, y);
}
```

by

```
public Figur(int x, int y) {
    posi = new Point(x, y);
}
```

to eliminate the NullPointer Exception.

Comment: Yeah, found that myself by now but thank you very much :) Can you explaint when I do need "= new..."? When I make instances of classes in contrast to simple fields (I think they're called like that?)?

Comment: If you want an instance of a class such must be an initialised Object to be an instance. By default all noted Objects (i.e. subclasses of Object), as long as not instantiated using _new_ are null.